# Remote server returns 404 when requesting an existing url

Tags: curl, http-status-code-404, remote-server

I've again got a strange problem:

I'm writing a crawler to index a specific site. For some weeks it worked fine and I only ran into problems when sending too many requests per hour.

But now I can't even access a single page.

But what's even stranger: I have to submit some form values via POST, but the server returns a 404 error - although the URL is definitely correct.

I implemented many techniques to prevent beeing recognized as a bot: changing user-agent, delays, and I'm sending a Referer-header to pretend the form was submitted from their own website.

May this again be a Spam- or DDOS-protection on their server? Or are there other possible sources of error?

Comment: If you're doing something "naughty", then your IP could well have been blocked.

Comment: But I also get an 404 when running the script on my local machine.

Comment: Using my browser -of course also on my local machine- everything works fine.

Comment: Check the output of your script using firebug or fiddler. It may be malformed

Comment: Which output? It's a PHP script and everything I got from CURL is "The requested URL returned error: 404"

Comment: Your script will be making an http call. Fiddler or wireshark can capture that call so you can see if it is well formed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, just solved it.

A very strange behaviour of the remote server caused the problem: when sending more parameters than expected, it returned 404 instead of ignoring not needed parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Be certain your URL doesn't have any extra data.

This:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.aspsite.com/');
```

Becomes (Notice the backslash removed):

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.aspsite.com');
```

If you are intending to use GET data, make sure your ASP file requests EXACTLY the data you send over.